# Backbone Marionette / ItemView tag

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I want to render a `<select>` with `<option>`'s based on a collection using Marionette's ItemView. Because the options need to have actual "values" in order for my App to work, I'm a bit unsure as to how I get Marionette to handle this? If I set a `tagName: 'option'` in my ItemView, I'm not sure how to add the option after rendering. I thought I could just let the `<option value="<%= id %>">` in the template, but that causes a double `<option>` element to render because I had already specified it in the `tagName` attribute of my ItemView. What's a best practice for doing this? My template looks like this:

```
<script type="text/template" id="sport-item-view">
    <option value="<%= id %>"><%= name %></option>
</script>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you using a CollectionView as the parent view type to render the collection of models in to the `select`? If you are, you shouldn't be.

Since the `option` items need everything in attributes, rendering a template for each option becomes painful as you've already encountered. Instead, use a single `ItemView` for the entire `select` box. An ItemView can take a collection in to it, and you can access that collection at `items` inside of the template. This makes it very trivial to create a select box out of a collection, with a single view:

```
<script type="text/html" id="select-template">
  <% _.each(items, function(item){ %>
    <option value="<%= item.id %>"><%= item.get("someValue") %></option>
  <% }) %>
</script>
```

```
var SelectView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
  tagName: "select"
});

var s = new SelectView({
  collection: myData
});

s.render();
```

The downside to this is that you only have 1 view for your select box, which means you have to read the selected value from the select box to figure out which model you are dealing with. But this is only a couple of lines of code, and it saves a ton of headache otherwise.

Comment: Thanks Derick! That's an elegant solution. I have it working now, but it's not firing any events (event something as simple as "click #select": 'foo' and then a function of foo: function(){ console.log('bar') }) won't register. Any thoughts? Code here: https://gist.github.com/StevenLangbroek/6214494

Comment: Since the views tag is the select box, you don't need to specify an element for the event. Just do `"click": "somemethod"` for the event config

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use [attributes](http://backbonejs.org/#View-attributes).

You can override constructor in this way:

```
constructor : function (options) {
  this.attributes = {
    value : options.model.id
  };
  ItemView.prototype.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

And your template will be like this:

```
<%= name %>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vpetrychuk/6Bk9T/

Comment: How do I get the current model's ID? I've tried this.model.get('id'), but that's obviously wrong...

Comment: This doesn't make much sense in my context: https://gist.github.com/StevenLangbroek/6212670

Comment: Forgive my ignorance here, but does it really make sense to create and maintain 2 view objects + 1 template just to render a select?

Comment: Yeah I probably shouldn't try to shoehorn everything in Marionette, got that from the other answer aswell. It's a lot of code for something trivial...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's better to handle this type of view in a more traditional sense by just adding options after render or perhaps on a triggered event. Here is what I did to add options dynamically based on fetched data:

```
        var mySelect = this.ui.mySelect; // a reference to select from ui hash
        mySelect.html('');  //clear

        //for each data item add an option
        _.each(items, function (item) { 
            mySelect .append($('<option/>', {
                value: item.id,
                text: item.description
            }));
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As this is part of a larger application and the select eventually drives another part of the UI I'd prefer to keep this within Backbone / Backbone.Marionette...

Comment: I don't think you understood me. This is inside one of the functions of a larger view. And you certainly can add event listeners on the select change or what ever you need to driver further UI rendering.